# Apache SVN server users management

Tags: svn

I'm a complete noob in SVN server management, so I'll say from the beginning that I could be asking something stupid in a dumb way. Unfortunately the guy who was managing svn in my company suddently left, and now I'm in due to add users and really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I did that:

I added the new users to passwd with:
htpasswd /etc/subversion/passwd user

then I created a new group into /etc/subversion/myrepos.acl file and I gave the "r" permission to the needed folder. This is my myrepos.acl file (a bit hidden more for privacy than for security):

```
[groups]
developers = aaa@bbb.com, lccc@ddd.com
production = eee@fff.com
administration = accounting@xxx.com, purchasing@xxx.com
guests = www

#
# Default priviledges
#

[/]
* =
@developers = rw

[/production]
@production = r
@administration = r
```

the two users that I have added are *accounting* and *purchasing*

now, if I try to connect with a client (I'm using tortoiseSvn client on Windows and Mac) I get the error "access forbidden". I get the same error if I try:

```
svn ls --username accounting@xxx.com https://*repository*
```

sometimes it gives me error immediately, other times it asks me the password, then it gives me the forbidden error:

```
~$ svn ls --username accounting@xxx.com https://*repository*
svn: E175013: Access to '/xxx...xxx/!svn/rvr/10786' forbidden
```

where "xxx...xxx" masks name of the company that is inside repository name.

now the strangest part: the user *purchasing* started working after some tries with tortoiseSVN client without any modification from me on the server, on the contrary it seems *accounting* does not want to work at all.

I have the doubt I should give authorisation to the users, somehow and or somewhere, but can't find it and actually I even miss the knoledge to know where to look for.

Thank you very much for every help you can give me, and sorry if I wrote dumb things, this is really far from my normal job.

regards

Answer (score 1):

well ok, as I was saying it was dumb.

I was trying to connecto to repository root folder, but I just gave the permission to /production folder to the users, that's why it gave me (correctly) the asnwer "forbidden".

I just leave here the questionand the answer, it could be helpfull for someone as noob as myself in the future.